# Osmium - How to keep only some tag names?

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim, osmium

I am using `osmium` tool in order to filter some data from a `planet.osm.pbf` file in order to inject that data into a `Nominatim` docker.

Here is my command: `osmium tags-filter planet-latest.osm.pbf place=city,town,village -o planet-light.osm.pbf --overwrite`

This is working as expected. However, it keeps a lot of useless data for me. For example, it keeps all the translations of the places.

Sample for Paris:

```
 "namedetails": {
            "ref": "75",
            "name": "Paris",
            "name:af": "Parys",
            "name:am": "ፓሪስ",
            "name:an": "París",
            "name:ar": "باريس",
            "name:ba": "Париж",
            "name:be": "Парыж",
            "name:nl": "Parijs",
            "name:no": "Paris",
            "name:oc": "París",
            "name:or": "ପ୍ୟାରିସ",
            "name:os": "Париж",
            "name:pa": "ਪੈਰਿਸ",
            "name:pl": "Paryż",
            "name:ps": "پاريس"
...
}
```

As I have a lot of records in my DB, all those translations are taking a lot of place and I do not need them.

Is there a way to only keep some tags? For example, I would like to keep only the following tags: `name`, `name:en`, `name:fr`.